# creating new association while creating the related record in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've these two models

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, :class_name => 'User'
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :requested_case, :class_name => 'Case', :foreign_key => :requested_case_id
end
```

and I want to create adminstration Interface for Case model using Active Admin, so when I create new case I can create new client for it in the same time, so I wrote the following lines of codes in the app/admin/cases.rb file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Case do
    form do |f|
        f.inputs "Basic Details"
            f.input :title
            f.input :Description
        end

        f.inputs :name => "Client Details", :for => :client do |c|
            c.input :name
            c.input :mobile
        end
        f.buttons
    end
end
```

so when I filed the inputs of client and click submit I got this error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::CasesController#create
User(#-625154418) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#82665960)
```

so any help please what's missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to your `app/admin/cases.rb` file

```
controller do
    def new
        @case = Case.new
        @case.build_client
    end
end
```

and don't forget to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for`  to your `case` model

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :client
```